# Can anyone help me identify this vintage road frame that has been repainted?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage, europe

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for taking a look for me!

Comment: Between 1960 and 1970, (bar-end shifters and drilled chainrings were common then)

Comment: What makes you say: repainted?

Comment: The lugged joint of the seat stays, seat tube and top tube looks a lot like a Pinarello, as do the dropouts. But then the fillet-brazed head tube is kinda confusing. (Somebody else was asking about a maybe-Pinarello a week or so ago, so it was fresh in my mind. I can't offer any more information; I'm no kind of expert.)

Comment: @carel good spotting - I note the head tube appears quite short, and that the fork doesn't have a lot of rake to it.  Both are more modern traits.   Lots of Campy parts which suggests its mostly original, but an old looking parallel rear mech.   I wonder if its more of an 80s bike.  The brake cable clamps on the top tube look late 70/early 80s.

Comment: The steel rims with eyelets suggest a touring-style wheel, but the bike's frame shows no rack mount points.  So all I can say conclusively is, that's a loverly bike and deserves to be ridden well.  And its too small for me, bother!

Comment: Claud Butler seems to have had an affinity for brazing and wrap-around seatstays, which would also be consistent with the French rims. Far from definitive, but a lead.  https://www.google.com/search?q=claud+butler+brazed&tbm=isch

Comment: If I'm seeing this correctly, it looks like a bi-laminate seat cluster--the top tube is fillet brazed to the joint, but the seat tube has a lugged connection. Pretty unusual. Apparently Claud Butler favors this design flourish: http://www.classiclightweights.co.uk/builders/cb-bilam-vincent.html

Answer (score 1):

The rims are Rigida, they are double wall aluminum, not steel.

I agree on the late 70's early 80's, might be a custom frame made for someone short.  The framebuilder would have gone lug-less due to the interference in the head tube, down tube top tube junctions.

Comment: Aluminium wheels would be unlikely to be original, so probably replacements some time in the 90s or later.